# How do virtual trusted platform modules protect data?

Tags: virtualization, tpm

From what I've read so far, vTPMs are able to securely store data on disk images. The disk images are encrypted and its keys are stored by the vTPM Manager. vTPM Manager also securely stores data on a disk image. However, I'm having difficulty figuring out how the vTPM Manager protects its data. Does it also encrypt its data? If so, where is the decryption key located and how does it protect against someone trying to steal its secrets? Any ideas are appreciated.

Ref: http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.5-testing/misc/vtpm.txt

Comment: According to your link a hardware TPM is involved so I'd assume all the secrets are actually kept in there.

Comment: Turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

That document appears to state that the data is sent through a virtual OS that acts as a virtual processor for the cryptographic data. There's a physical TPM installed on the device to which the OS acts as a front-end, using a virtual hardware driver for communication. The software acts as a middle-man for the communication, most likely for accessing the TPM more securely by bridging it and the host with the Mini-os using software encryption. The key difference (pun intended) between the vTPM and the physcial TPM is that the keys and NVRAM are stored in the presumably TPM encrypted disk image which is to be made by the user. It says any empty image will do, of around 2MB. It's a mirror of the hardware device that uses the main module for resources, and stores data in its own reservoir.

Cracking it may be difficult. If the key is stored in the hardware TPM, then you're not gonna have much luck getting at it. It's probably far from being brute-forced, so that's out. Some encryption methods have security issues, but most credible programs use AES. While the cryptographic data is in-use, it might be possible to get it from RAM (the problem with almost every software based method). However, if it's very well integrated, it may all be secured. There's not much data in that document save for installation instructions and the topography.